# Imaginary term solution in the limit $v\ll c$ of relativistic Lagrangian

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, causality

The relativistic action is

$$
S=- m \int_a^b d s.
$$

With metric $ds^2=dx^2 - dt^2$, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
S&=\pm m \int_a^b \sqrt{dx^2-dt^2}\\
&=\pm mc\int_a^b dt\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2-1}\\
&=\pm mc\int_a^b dt\sqrt{\dot{x}^2-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Developing $\sqrt{\dot{x}^2-1}$ as a series around $\dot{x}^2$, we get:

$$
\sqrt{\dot{x}^2-1}=i - \frac{i \dot{x}^2}{2} + O[\dot{x}]^4.
$$

---

If we had instead taken the metric to be $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2$, we would have obtained the usual non-relativistic limit:

$$
\sqrt{1-\dot{x}^2}=1 - \frac{ \dot{x}^2}{2} + O[\dot{x}]^4.
$$

So, why is $ds^2=dx^2 - dt^2$ "incorrect", but $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2$ "correct"? What does the imaginary term mean?

Comment: You can always multiply the action by a constant, so there is no difference.

Comment: The trajectory of a massive point particle is always timelike $dt^2-dx^2>0$.

Comment: @Qmechanic: The OP is using the -+++ metric.

Comment: @knzhou: That should be an answer.